# Setting up Nav2 on real robot

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

I'm working on building my own SLAM robot as an educational project, and I've been following along the excellent [guide](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/index.html) on setting up Nav2. I'm a bit stuck, and here's why:

My robot is running a Raspberry Pi 4 (Ubuntu 22.04) *headlessly*, but the Nav2 setup guide assumes (or maybe requires? I'm not sure) the use of Gazebo. I made it from the beginning all the way through the URDF set up section, but starting from the [Setting Up Odometry](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/odom/setup_odom.html) it gets a bit Gazebo-heavy.

I'd appreciate some help with regards to either:

- Knowing which parts of the tutorial(s) to ignore (since I'm not using sim) without skipping critical steps in getting my real robot moving
- Using a different guide (if there exists one) that is less sim-oriented and more geared toward setting up a physical robot with Nav2

Thanks in advance and huge kudos to everyone making Nav2 happen!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409664/setting-up-nav2-on-real-robot/) by [coatwolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/117662/coatwolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found [this course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLunhqkrRNRhYAffV8JDiFOatQXuU-NnxT) on YouTube by Articulated Robotics to be extremely helpful in getting things running on a physical robot, not only nav2 but also slam_toolbox and more. Huge props to the creator.

---

Originally posted by [coatwolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/117662/coatwolf/) with karma: 13 on 2023-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Turtlebot4 code base is open source and includes launch and yaml config files that you might be able to repurpose on your bot.

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot4/tree/galactic/turtlebot4_navigation

The manual is at https://turtlebot.github.io/turtlebot4-user-manual/software/nav2.html

---

Originally posted by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) with karma: 327 on 2022-11-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [coatwolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/117662/coatwolf/) on 2022-11-22**:
GREAT suggestion, don't know why I didn't think of Turtlebot. Thank you.

**Comment by [Zermelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/124945/zermelo/) on 2022-11-23**:
Actually I took a a look at the code and i don't understand what the turttlebot4_navigator, does ? do I need this ?